# Ubuntu doesn't boot after installation

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad from a bootable USB device. The automatic installation of Grub failed so I followed the instructions for manually installing Grub which works without errors. Now Grub doesn't load after restarting the laptop; there is only a menu where I can choose from which device I want to boot but there it stucks. At the moment I don't know if Grub is correctly installed or if the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Does it boot Windows?

Comment: I did not install Windows. Previously I had installed Debian which worked without this error.

Comment: @jochen [The answers detailed here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) almost always fix this problem, even when there is no Windows or other OS installed alongside Ubuntu. Sometimes the Ubuntu installer fails to provide a working GRUB boot loader installation, and reinstalling GRUB to the master boot record (as detailed in those answers) usually fixes this.